# Category theoretic proof that graphs and intersections gives equalizers

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

I want to understand the proof that equalizers can be gotten from graphs and intersections in the category of sets.

I am working on exercise 3.34 in Lawvere and Rosebrughs Sets for Mathematics.

I am in the last step of the exercise trying to prove that the $(i,E)$ constructed is an equalizer of two arbitrary $f,g:A \to B$. I use the notation $\gamma_f,\gamma_g:A \to A \times B$ for the associated graphs and $j=\gamma_f \cap \gamma_g: E \to A \times B$ for their intersection where $i:E \to A$ is the proof that $j \subseteq \gamma_g$ and $j \subseteq \gamma_f$.

The last step of the proof amount to showing that if $x:T \to A$ is arbitrary and $fx=gx$ then $x=i\bar{x}$ for a unique $\bar{x}:T \to E$. Uniqueness is not the issue, since $i$ is mono by construction, but the existence gives me some troubles.

My strategy has been to use somehow that the condition $x \in i$, which is equivalent to $x=i\bar{x}$, holds iff $y \in j$ for $y=\gamma_g x = \gamma_f x$. The direction of $\Rightarrow$ is easy enough, but I can't seem to show the implication in the $\Leftarrow$ direction.

Any help or hint is much appreciated!